# I want to replace an html content with my own content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, replace, attributes, tags

Below is the html code and I want to replace the content with " This is html code ".
The code runs without errors but nothing changed and content remains same.

I want to replace "A full stack developer." with "This is html code"

```
soup='<meta content="A full stack developer." name="description"/>'
```

My code:

```
for i in soup.find_all("meta", "description"):

    var1=i.string
    var1.replace_with(var1.replace(var1, 'This is html code '))
    print(var1)
    
print(soup)
```

By the above method I am not getting error but the content attribute remains same.

I have tried different ways as well but I get this error:

### 'str' object has no attribute 'replace_with'

Can anyone guide me how to replace the content attribute with your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access tag attribute, use `[ ]`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '<meta content="A full stack developer." name="description" />'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

# replace the attribute "content":
soup.find("meta", {"name": "description"})["content"] = "This is html code"
print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<meta content="This is html code" name="description"/>
```

Comment: Now I get this error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Thanks, I figured out it, used soup.find instead of soup.find_all.